# Some of options Plotly modebar didn't appear in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

This is an example from the book https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html, this is the link https://github.com/cpsievert/plotly_book/blob/master/code/shiny-drill-down-pie/app.R
The problem is some of options of modebar didn’t show up like normal, then I try so many ways, but it’s the same.

[Modebar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI5ay.png)

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) # just for `%||%`

load("sales.rda")
categories <- unique(sales$category)

ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("pie"), uiOutput("back"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # for maintaining the current category (i.e. selection)
  current_category <- reactiveVal()

  # report sales by category, unless a category is chosen
  sales_data <- reactive({
    if (!length(current_category())) {
      return(count(sales, category, wt = sales))
    }
    sales %>%
      filter(category %in% current_category()) %>%
      count(sub_category, wt = sales)
  })

  # Note that pie charts don't currently attach the label/value
  # with the click data, but we can leverage `customdata` as a workaround
  output$pie <- renderPlotly({
    d <- setNames(sales_data(), c("labels", "values"))
    plot_ly(d) %>%
      add_pie(labels = ~labels, values = ~values, customdata = ~labels) %>%
      layout(title = current_category() %||% "Total Sales")
  })

  # update the current category if the clicked value matches a category
  observe({
    cd <- event_data("plotly_click")$customdata[[1]]
    if (isTRUE(cd %in% categories)) current_category(cd)
  })

  populate back button if category is chosen
  output$back <- renderUI({
    if (length(current_category()))
      actionButton("clear", "Back", icon("chevron-left"))
  })

  clear the chosen category on back button press
  observeEvent(input$clear, current_category(NULL))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: When you say "some of the options of modebar didn't show up like normal", what does that mean? What options did you expect to show up that did not? This example is a pie chart, and many of the modebar options have to do with adjustments to axes, which have no relevance to a pie chart.

Comment: I just add picture there

Comment: What are you expecting it to show? Why is that picture not what you expect?